# Is loading a model within another CodeIgniter model appropriate?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an architectural question that has been bothering me.

Codeigniter defines there [model](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html) as such.  Now there are times when a model is closely tied to another.  I.e. User and Security.

**Is it bad practice to access another model within a model?**

i.e.

```
class User extends CI_model 
{
    function getUser() 
    {
        $this->load->model('User');
        $user = // load user 

        $this->load->model('Security');
        $security = // load security

        $user->security = $security;
    }
}
```

Some how it doesn't feel 'kosher' to me.   It feels like I need to have a DAO or some sort of DAL on top which can then load both models and do the necessary fetching while leaving the basic CRUD and model specific operations in the model.  And if we do create a separate layer, there doesn't seem like a logical place to put them in the Codeigniter framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the sad part: CodeIgniter does not implement MVC design pattern. It just mimics Rails architecture. There is a difference.

What you call "models" in CodeIgniter, are usually implementation of [active record](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) (anti)pattern. They combine the responsibilities of domain business logic with storage logic.

So, if you are working with standard CI code, then you are not supposed to do it. You cannot call `$this->load->model()`  within another [`CI_Model`](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Model.php#L44) instance, because it does no have such capabilities [`CI_Controller`](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Controller.php).

Instead you would have to override default `__construct()`, which would  access the global instance of CI and bind it to `$this->load` variable. Basically it would be a hack.

You will be better off instantiating the "models" in the controller and injecting those dependencies manually.

---

Then again .. you are using CodeIgniter, so who cares about development principles.

Comment: I usually create a class in the library directory to be used as domain object, then load all needed "models" from there (so these models are just kind of data mappers). In this way I just call the library class in the controller. Otherwise, in large applications, controllers get very messy using only CI "models".

Answer (score 0):

Check out DataMapper ORM

[DataMapper ORM for CodeIgniter](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/)

From the site:

> DataMapper is an Object Relational Mapper written in PHP for CodeIgniter. It is designed to map your Database tables into easy to work with objects, fully aware of the relationships between each other.

Comment: Not quite sure why this answer was down-voted. Seemed a perfectly reasonable suggestion. An ORM is what you're looking for if you wanting to set up relations between models.